# Very strange problem functions that run normally will not report an error but will report an error when started in debug mode

Tags: go, exception

Direct runs are error free
When debugging a program
The second time you enter the recursive function, an error is reported
Do not skip methods to get into methods
This is my function okay
Very strange question

```golang
type Student struct {
    Name string
    //排序
    Sort int
    //parent
    Parent int
    //level
    Level int
    Id    int
}
func main() {
    var data []Student = []Student{
        {Name: "家用电器", Sort: 1, Parent: 0, Level: 1, Id: 1},
        {Name: "电脑办公", Sort: 2, Parent: 0, Level: 1, Id: 2},
        {Name: "男装", Sort: 3, Parent: 0, Level: 1, Id: 3},
        {Name: "手机", Sort: 1, Parent: 2, Level: 2, Id: 4},
        {Name: "数码", Sort: 2, Parent: 1, Level: 2, Id: 5},
        {Name: "汽车", Sort: 3, Parent: 1, Level: 2, Id: 6},
        {Name: "男装2", Sort: 1, Parent: 3, Level: 2, Id: 7},
        {Name: "男装2下层皮裤", Sort: 1, Parent: 7, Level: 3, Id: 8},
        {Name: "汽车2下层拖拉机", Sort: 1, Parent: 6, Level: 3, Id: 9},
    }
    result := make([]Student, len(data))
    flag := make([]bool, len(data))

    index := 0
    FindTest(&result, data, flag, 1, 0, &index)
}
```

[image]
Here is error log:

```
//exception
0 {家用电器 1 0 1 1}
Exception 0xc000001d 0x0 0x0 0x4bb723
PC=0x4bb723

main.FindTest(0xc000089d58, 0xc000089da0, 0x9, 0x9, 0xc00000a0d0, 0x9, 0x9, 0x2, 0x1, 0xc000089d40)
    F:/golang/gostu/ptr/chan2.go:36 +0x573
main.FindTest(0xc000089d58, 0xc000089da0, 0x9, 0x9, 0xc00000a0d0, 0x9, 0x9, 0x1, 0x0, 0xc000089d40)
    F:/golang/gostu/ptr/chan2.go:47 +0x465
main.main()
    F:/golang/gostu/ptr/chan2.go:32 +0x184
rax     0xc000089b10
rbx     0xc000089880
rcx     0xc000036000
rdi     0xc00008e008
rsi     0x19
rbp     0xc000089ce0
rsp     0xc000089bb8
r8      0x83fd88
r9      0xc0000896e0
```

Comment: The problem appears to be in the `FindTest` function, which you did not show us.

Comment: Such "heisenbugs" are typically indicative of some unsynchronized concurrent access to memory: when program runs under a debugger, _timings_ of various operations may well be different form those under "normal" circumstances—especally if you literally suspend one (or more) of the goroutines by using break points in the debugger.

Comment: Unfortunately, since it's Windows™, you may also experience an antivirus software intervening in interesting ways.

Comment: `func  FindTest (result *[]Student,data []Student,flag []bool ,level ,parent int ,index *int){
 if level>4{
  return
 }
 for i:=0;i< len(data)&&flag[i]==false;i++{
  if data[i].Level==level&&data[i].Parent==parent&&flag[i]==false{
   (*result)[*index]=data[i]
   fmt.Println(*index,data[i])
   *index++
   flag[i]=true
   FindTest(result,data,flag,level+1,data[i].Id,index)
  }
 }
}`

Comment: @大黑猫 Your code works well in my ENV. 这是算法题吗，还是业务？

Comment: @kostix which antivirus software can make this issue? curious

Comment: @p1gd0g 业务呢所以比较关心是不是函数的问题

Comment: 无法复现无从下手。可以试一下这种写法能不能符合你的要求。https://play.golang.org/p/lZ6y2uiV8y-